# using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, javascriptserializer

in my asp.net webform application i want to send a variable from my codebehind to the .aspx page for using in my js codes

codebehind:

```
   public string GetSomestring()
    {         
        JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return j.Serialize("#000");         
    }
```

and in my page in js i have this code

```
 <script>
            var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };

            var color= '<%= GetSomestring()%>';


            var lineChartData = {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: color,
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: [12,23,12,43,10,3]
                    }
                ]
            }

            window.onload = function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
                    responsive: true
                });
            }


</script>
```

the string returned to my .aspx page because when i write the below code it execute rightly

```
 var color = '<%= GetSomestring()%>';
            alert(color);
```

and when i write this code my js execute rightly

```
var color = "#000";
```

i dont know what is the problem that my first code not execute rightly and pointStrokeColor not get the "color"

Comment: Why not just return a string literal instead of serializing it? Can't you just return the color value as string without doing any serialization? Try return "#000"; instead of return j.Serialize("#000");

Comment: when i want to return an array instead of string i use Serialize but when i return array with serialize and i want that this array be the value of field data my code dont work rightly

Comment: If you would return array then your second passing test is not correct. For second test try using an array of colors and see if it works. I think you are using chart.js api and as per documentation it seems it only supports only one color value for pointStrokeColor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from server in javascript you should use **Ajax** for that using **webmethod** in codebehind.
Here is some sample code may it help you.

**Code Behind:**

```
       [WebMethod]
       public string GetSomestring()
          {         
            JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return j.Serialize("#000");         
           }
```

**View: "Client Side"**

```
       var result;
     $.ajax({
                url: ../PageName/GetSomestring",
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data, status) {
                    result = data.d;
                },
                error: function (requeset, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
   var color= result ;
```

**OR just try  this:**
**Convert color into color.value**

```
              <script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };

        var color= '<%= GetSomestring()%>';


        var lineChartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: color.value,
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [12,23,12,43,10,3]
                }
            ]
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
                responsive: true
            });
        }
```

Convert  color into color.value

```
             pointStrokeColor: color.value,
```

Hopefully this will help you.Thanks